See an arbitrary SQL statement in oracle enterprise manager
I like to see any sql statement in the Oracle Enterprise Manager (oem) Cloud Control 13c, e.g. in the active session history.
A simple select is not shown in any view. After some research I found in the manual (e.g.: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/owp-sql-monitoring-128746.pdf), that SQL monitoring is automatically started when a SQL statement either runs in parallel or has consumed at least 5 seconds of combined CPU and I/O time in a single
execution.
So from my point of view I must be sure that an SQL statement runs at least 5 seconds to appear in the oem.
Can I do this by an addition in the SQL statement (like an sleep), or can I change the default in the oem?
Is there an best practice for this?
Any help is appreciated
Update:
Thanks to Paul W: /*+ monitor */ did the trick.
select /*+ monitor */ * from table;

makes the query appear in the oem.

Active Session History (ASH) and SQL Monitoring are two different things. ASH is always on and gathering at 1 second intervals - if OEM (which I personally don't use, so I'm guessing) delays for 5 seconds, that's probably because it is querying the ASH data (in gv$active_session_history, which you can query yourself) every 5 seconds. That doesn't mean that you don't have ASH data, just that you aren't seeing it yet in the OEM graph. That might be configurable, which would be an OEM question, but a gv$ query more often than that can be a bit much on a large RAC system, so 5 may be a minimum

SQL Monitoring adds additional information, primarily row counts emitted from each row source (plan step) which is useful in understanding why time is being spent where it is, but not necessary. That is what your bold statement refers to - when SQL Monitor engages. It has no relation to ASH. If you are trying to get SQL Monitor (row counts by plan step) data to kick in immediately and not wait for 5 seconds, you can add a /*+ monitor */ hint to your SQL. But only do this when it's actually needed - there's a reason why Oracle only turns this on for "interesting" SQL and not on everything.

Actually ASH uses sampling. Oracle can not track execution details of every SQL. SQL captured have to either exceed certain exec time, or have to be executed at least 10000x times. Exact numbers are described in some metalink note, and can by changed by underscore parameters.
Also note, that some performance metrics might be visible only AFTER SQL successfully finishes. If you cancel running SQL some performance metrics might be lost.
